# removing data in nested arrays in mongodb shell

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested

i'm new in *Nosql*. i'm using *Mongodb* *shell* for the first time. i've seen other related solutions but non of them is working for me. i have an object that contains several nested arrays i want to remove the data that are not in 2016. the collection looks like this.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("58754aa6b10700f77b90c018"),
"results" : [
    {
        "series" : [
            {
                "name" : "light",
                "columns" : [
                    "time",
                    "agent_id",
                    "device_id",
                    "rpi_id",
                    "type",
                    "value"
                ],
                "values" : [
                    [
                        "1970-01-01T00:00:01.474264311Z",
                        null,
                        "2:1",
                        "b07882d6-5c28-597b-89f9-d250f74b0bad",
                        "light",
                        "231"
                    ],
                    [
                        "1970-01-01T00:00:01.474280348Z",
                        null,
                        "1:1",
                        "b07882d6-5c28-597b-89f9-d250f74b0bad",
                        "light",
                        "404"
                    ],
                    [
                        "1970-01-01T00:00:01.474280526Z",
                        null,
                        "2:1",
                        "b07882d6-5c28-597b-89f9-d250f74b0bad",
                        "light",
                        "239"
                    ],
                    [
                        "2016-12-21T23:36:32Z",
                        "fce19d9c-3bba-5b18-9854-f86776b47a9c",
                        "4",
                        null,
                        null,
                        "1019"
                    ],
                    [
                        "2016-12-21T23:36:56Z",
                        "fce19d9c-3bba-5b18-9854-f86776b47a9c",
                        "1",
                        null,
                        null,
                        "1023"
                    ],
                    [
                        "2016-12-21T23:37:00Z",
                        "fce19d9c-3bba-5b18-9854-f86776b47a9c",
                        "5",
                        null,
                        null,
                        "1022"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

for example i tried this query to find them but the result is the whole collection:

```
db.lights.find({"results.series.values": {$elemMatch : {$elemMatch: {$not : /^2016/} } } })
```

i'll be so grateful if anyone could answer it.